# Django error in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I have a problem trying to setup django project:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',


url(r'^admin/', include(webshop.admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^about/', include(webshop.views.about)),
url(r'^products/', include(webshop.views.available_products)),
url(r'^products/(\d+)/', include(webshop.views.productview)),
```

and I get the next error:

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'webshop' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/Python/myProject/myProject/urls.py in <module>, line 11
```

UPDATE: 
Thanks, it was nub, mistake.

Now, I'm getting this error:

> Exception Value:
>   No module named about

Thanks for help, it my first time using django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your included url file paths in quotes:

```
url(r'^admin/', include('webshop.admin.site.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0):

NameError shows up when you've not defined a name -- any name that you're trying to evaluate.

[From the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError):

> Raised when a local or global name is not found. This applies only to unqualified names. The associated value is an error message that includes the name that could not be found.

So this code would cause `NameError` to be thrown at the second line assigning to `a`:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    a = c + (a * b)
```

In order to fix your problem, you should probably <strike>add an `import webshop` to your code before you reference it</strike> use quoted strings, as in [this example in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

Comment: Normally, yes, but `include` doesn't expect an imported module - it takes a path to import. Or some other options, but for this use case it needs to be a path string. Well, actually, the docs are ambiguous now that I look at it - "URLconf module (or module name)". So maybe a full `import webshop.admin.site.urls` would work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include